# Name of the department that has largest number of employees

Tags: sql, database

I have two tables:

[Here you can see attributes of both tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJo7N.png)

I have written a code that shows the number of employees each department has.

```
select department_id, count(employee_id) 
from employees
group by department_id
order by count(employee_id) desc
```

[(See the output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmLTK.png)

I would like to know the way how to do it. I guess I need to join tables but still can't do it.

I use SQL Developer by Oracle

Thanks for your response!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  However, this is a pretty basic query using `group by` and `join`, so you should also show your attempts.

Comment: Your query seems perfect. What's the problem here?

Comment: I just want the specific department name that has the largest number of workers.

Comment: Please, [do not post images of data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#285557), paste it as text.

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems perfect. Are you trying to get department names along with department_id? Then you can join Department table.

```
  select e.department_id,d.department_name, count(e.employee_id) TotalEmployee from employees e 
          inner join departmnet d on e.department_id=d.department_id
   group by e.department_id
   order by count(e.employee_id) desc
```